# Как заменить символ новой строки на тег <br>?

Tags: flask, wtforms

Заранее спасибо за ответы

Пишу приложение на Flask, есть простая форма ввода
сообщения. Сообщение вводится и сохраняется в базе данных. Но все сообщение получается в одну строчку.

Подскажите пожалуйста как при отображении сообщения символы новой строки ("\r\n", "\r", "\n") перевести в тег

**# model.py (модель в базе данных)**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
```

**# index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WWW Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ post.body }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Самостоятельные попытки решить проблему были?

Comment: Пока думаю над тем чтобы сделать replace в строке на br, затем экранировать все теги кроме br самостоятельно и включить режим
{{ post.body | safe }} чтобы jinja не экранировала мой тег br

Comment: `<div style="white-space: pre-wrap">{{ post.body }}</div>` и не надо ничего заменять

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!
Такое решение намного лучше)

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

Поправил модель базы данных и добавил метод

**# model.py**

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    body_html = db.Column(db.Text)

    @staticmethod
    def on_changed_body(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
        value = value.replace('\r\n', '<br>')
        value = value.replace('\r', '<br>')
        value = value.replace('\n', '<br>')
        target.body_html = bleach.clean(value, tags=['br'], strip=True)


db.event.listen(Post.body, 'set', Post.on_changed_body)
```

Вывод результата

**# index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>WWW Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.body_html %}
          {{ post.body_html | safe }}
        {% else %}
          {{ post.body }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```